# Convert numerical result to a letter in Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I just wanted to know how to convert the result of a calculation into a simple `YES` or `NO` outcome. I.e. if the value is *less than* `X` then 'YES' you need to reorder, if the value is *greater than* `X` then `NO` you don't need to reorder.

I'm sure it is probably simple, but I'm a graphics type hippy and this is out of my normal comfort zone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
=IF(A1<X1,"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a boolean value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) with the following:

```
=A1<X1
```